# Dynamically update the table on selecting checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I'm very new to php and have been given the task to update the table in the database when user select the check box and then edit the information in the text box. I'm able to pull the information from database and display it on the screen, however I'm not too sure how to update the database when user selects the checkbox and update the field

Here is what I want to achieve:
1) On clicking the checkbox, the row gets editable.
2) After updating the field value, and clicking button "update", the value gets updated in the d/b

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="20%">Field Name</th>
                    <th width="52%">Field Text</th>
                    <th width="32%">Select to Update</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
            <?php
                if($table = true)
                {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                    $fieldName[] = $row['fieldName'];
                    $fieldText[] = $row['fieldText'];
                    $fieldID[]   = $row['ID'];

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['fieldName']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['fieldText']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."<input type= 'checkbox' value='{$row['ID']}',  name = ID[]>"."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }

                }
                else
                {echo "No results found";}
            ?>
            </table>
</div>
```

Not sure how to proceed further. After checking forums, I found that Jquery is the way to go, but not sure how to make the field updatable. 
Please note that I haven't provided the code for the "Update" functionality.

Comment: Can't help much on jQuery, and not too clear on what you meant by clicking `update table`, is that a button? However if you want to update when the checkbox is ticked, you can create a form surrounding your table and use `onChange="this.form.submit()"` in the form tag to submit the form whenever a checkbox is checked.

Comment: yes, its a button. updated the questions as well. possible to show me how to do this, I'm noob in php.. struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am not good in jquery. But i think for this u could use

```
$('.your-check-box').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked)
    {
       //change text on inputs
    }
    else {
       //change inputs on text         
    }
});
```

this is quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qr4ova98/

For DB update u need to send ajax with data on event.

Comment: Can you help me understanding this code:       if(this.checked) {
            $(parent[0]).html('<input class="someValue" value="'+$(parent[0]).text()+'">');
        $(parent[1]).html('<input class="someValue" value="'+$(parent[1]).text()+'">');
    }
    else {
     $(parent[0]).html($(parent[0]).children().val());
        $(parent[1]).html($(parent[1]).children().val());
    }

Comment: When checkbox is checked up we paste inputs with values of inner text instead of just text. Parents indexes (0,1) depending on how much elements do u have in your table row, in your example its 3 (including checkbox). And when checkbox is checked down we just replace inputs with text.